# Using multiple order types in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a table which lists all the employees with some information. Initially when the table loads, all the employees in the table are sorted by their Status and for this I implemented a custom order function in my controller.

Employee.html

```
   <table class="table">
            <thead class="active">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <a href="" ng-click="orderByemployeeField=sorterFunc; reverseemployeeSort = !reverseemployeeSort">
                        employee ID <span ng-show="orderByemployeeField == sorterFunc"><span ng-show="!reverseemployeeSort">^</span><span ng-show="reverseemployeeSort">v</span></span>
                    </a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href="" ng-click="orderByemployeeField='employeeState'; reverseemployeeSort = !reverseemployeeSort">
                        employee State <span ng-show="orderByemployeeField == 'employeeState'"><span ng-show="!reverseemployeeSort">^</span><span ng-show="reverseemployeeSort">v</span></span>
                    </a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href="" ng-click="orderByemployeeField='daysCount'; reverseemployeeSort = !reverseemployeeSort">
                        Days Count <span ng-show="orderByemployeeField == 'daysCount'"><span ng-show="!reverseemployeeSort">^</span><span ng-show="reverseemployeeSort">v</span></span>
                    </a>
                </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody ng-if="!fromOffice">
            <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees | filter:search  | orderBy: orderByemployeeField:reverseemployeeSort" id="row{{employee.assetId}}" ng-mouseover="showRowTitle($event, employee)"
                ng-click="showemployeesOrAlarmsSiteMap($event,employee.assetId)" style="cursor: pointer" ng-dblclick="employeeInformation(employee)">
                <td><a href="" ui-sref="app.cesemployeedetails({ employeeID:employee.assetId })" style="text-decoration: underline">{{employee.assetId}}</a></td>
                <td>{{employee.employeeState}}</td>
                <td>{{employee.daysCount}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody ng-if="fromOffice">
            <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees | filter:search | orderBy: orderByemployeeField:reverseemployeeSort | orderBy : customOrder"
                ng-if="employee.siteId == selectedSiteId" style="cursor: pointer">
                <td>{{employee.assetId}}}</td>
                <td>{{employee.employeeState}}</td>
                <td>{{employee.daysCount}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

EmployeeCtrl.js

```
$scope.customOrder = function (item) {
        var empStatus = item.empState;
        switch (empStatus) {
            case 'Working':
                return 1;

            case 'Leave':
                return 2;

            case 'Resigned':
                return 4;

            case 'Someother':
                return 3;
        }
    };
```

Now that the table is sorted based on employee status, when I click on any other headers like employee id it sorts the rows based on the employee id's within that initial sort order. For example: the employee id's within the state "Leave" are sorted and then for each category. What I am looking for is that initially the table should be sorted using employee state and then once I click on any other columns they should be sorted by taking that column into consideration. Could anyone let me know how I could achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting ordering within the initial sort order is because you have two orderBy's on your ng-repeat.  You should only be sorting on one field at a time in your use case. A better way to do it would be to make your customOrder function general purpose that can handle sorting any of the columns you click.  You would just need to pass in the column you are sorting on, and then apply your sorting algorithm for that column.

Comment: I was able to add a customOrder function to the Status column. Now when the page loads how can I say that the table should be ordered by the Status by default.what should be the default value to $scope.orderByemployeeField if I need to sort it by Employee status as the function takes in a parameter.